# Adding an array of floating points

Tags: assembly

Since FPU Stack only has 8 slots, how can I add more elements. I have an array of 10 elements that I need to add. Here's what I have so far

```
_Average proc

        finit

        mov ecx, [esp + 4]      ; get the number of elements
        mov ebx, [esp + 8]      ; get the address of the array

        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx]     ; get first element of array
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 8] ; get second element of array
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 16]; this element is now at the top of the stack
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 24]
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 32]
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 40]
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 48]
        fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx + 56]
        ;fld        REAL8 PTR [ebx + 64]
        ;fld        REAL8 PTR [ebx + 72]

        fadd
        fadd
        fadd
        fadd
        fadd
        fadd
        fadd
        ;fadd
        ;fadd
        fwait   ; if necessary wait for the co-processor to finish
        ret
_Average endp

extern "C" double Average (int, double []);

void main ()
    {
    double Array1 [10] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.0};

    double Array2 [11] = {-1.1, -2.2, -3.3, -4.4, -5.5, -6.6, -7.7, -8.8, -9.9, -10.0, -11.0};

    cout << "Average of Array1 is " << Average (10, Array1) << endl;

    cout << "Average of Array2 is " << Average (11, Array2) << endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep a running total instead of loading them all and then adding them all.

Comment: Also, it will use the pipeline better.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to load first then add, you can just do this:

```
fld    real8 ptr [ebx]
fadd   real8 ptr [ebx + 8]
fadd   real8 ptr [ebx + 16]
fadd   real8 ptr [ebx + 24]
```

and so on...

Comment: oh thanks for the tip Fabian, I ended up setting a loop just like Carl Norum recommended. Curious to know though, if I were to implement your recommendation, would I not still need a loop or does using fadd let me keep adding elements beyond 8.

Comment: `fadd [foo]` doesn't put anything onto the stack, it just adds foo to whatever is currently the top of the stack. It's roughly equivalent to the sequence `fld [foo]` / `faddp st(1), st`, except it doesn't actually need a free stack slot. For any kind of stack-based computation, you don't let the stack grow for a long time, you generally reduce as soon as possible.